# Ajax retorna próprio código e executa

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tenho uma pagina que deve gerar `selects` ao clicar no icone de +.

```
    <div class='form-group' id='div_selects'>
                <label for='materiais_defeito'>Material com defeito?</label>&nbsp&nbsp<i href="#" class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" onclick="gerarSelect()"></i>
            </div>
```

Fiz isso usando `Ajax`. Está funcionando, ou seja, gera os `selects`. Porém acima do `select` vem todo o codigo da função `Ajax` junto como uma `string`, que é:

```
   function gerarSelect() 
    {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("div_selects").appendChild(newElement);
    }

}

xmlhttp.open("GET","../ajax/gerar_selects.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

 }
```

O `php` que gera os `selects` é:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION["logado"])
    header("Location:../views/login_tela.php");


require "../bd/conecta_banco.php";
require "ajax.js";

$produtos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE visibilidade = 'visivel'");

echo "<select class='form-control'>";

while ($produto = $produtos->fetch_object()) 
    echo "<option value='".$produto->id."'>".$produto->modelo."</option>";

echo "</select>";

 ?>
```

Ja busquei bastante na internet e não encontrei nada parecido. Quando havia era que por alguma razão o codigo era interpretado como uma `string`, porem no meu caso ele foi executado também.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que você adicionou esse `require`:

```
require "ajax.js";
```

O PHP tenta interpretar o conteúdo desse arquivo, mas como não existe uma tag `<?php` ele imprime tudo como se fosse HTML puro.

Arquivos JS devem ser incluídos somente através da tag [`script`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) no HTML.

Comment: Claro e direto kkk +1

Comment: Foi isso msm. Obrigado pessoal!